# using dynamic sql in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that takes as a parameter the following variable that holds a table name, `@percapHist`. It will hold a value something like '`percaphist1408`'.

I want to count the number of records in the table and save the value in a variable to be used later. I have now tried using `dynamic sql`. the statement compiles quickly but when run it says i must declare the `scalar variable @percapcount`. here is the dynamic sql statement that is being used inside the store procedure.

```
SET @tsql = 'SELECT @percapCount = Count(socSecNo) FROM ' + @percapHist
EXEC(@tsql)
```

when i examine the variable @tsql after the above statement is executed i see the following

```
SELECT @percapCount = Count(socSecNo) FROM percapHist1408
```

but when i run the above EXEC I get the 'must declare scalar variable `@perapcount`'

Comment: you have to declare variable  before use, say declare @perapcount int

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a value from dynamic SQL, then use `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @tsql nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @percapCount int;

SET @tsql = 'SELECT @percapCount = Count(socSecNo) FROM ' + @percapHist;

EXEC sp_executesql @tsql, N'@percapCount INT OUTPUT', @percapCount = @percapCount OUTPUT;
```

Comment: i tried the above exactly as you have it. it compiles ok but when i run it by stepping through the lines of code the highlighted line rests on the EXEC statement and part of the SELECT statement which follows. For some reason it doesnt realize the line statement ends at the ; after output.

Comment: @BillG . . . That is strange behavior.  The semicolon is standard in SQL Server for ending statements.